# wxPython install error on windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, wxpython

I have installed on my PC python 2.7.3 and I'm trying to install wxPython add-on. On windows 7 and ubutu everything runs OK, but on windows 8.1 i get this error when i run the executable files download from wxPython download page:

[image]

Anyone knows how to pass it? I also installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 that I saw in many thread solved the problem. 
 
I can't use easy-install because the archive doesn't have setup.py, and with PIP this is the log that is generating: http://pastebin.com/zdGZwHny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can install it via the [Python Unofficial Librarie](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython)s page.

Comment: This is saying that I don't have Python installed on my computer (the exact error is: Python 2.7 is required, which was not found in the registry), but i have it on default directory: C:\Python27

Comment: Then try reinstalling with the latest version, 2,7,6.

Comment: I solved by copying into windows registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python to HKLM\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\Python

Comment: @MikeT Thats awesome then. Its difficult to daignose the problem unless you know whats exactly going on in your PC. Now you can try installing wxPython from the link I just gave you. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: yes, that helped me, but 1 more question how can i get the latest version because 2.8 seems to be older. I saw 3.0 on wxpython webpage

Comment: Try installing [this](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython3.0-win64-3.0.0.0-py27.exe) then.

Comment: doesnt work, i get the result described in my post :(

Comment: @MikeT Then it might be an issue with Windows 8. I will need to know more before I can actually solve the problem.